# discrete mathematic Question that i need help with please

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Determine the number of integer solutions of $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 = 32$ where $x_i > 3$ for $1 ≤ i ≤ 5$.

Comment: Try to use Stars and Bars as described at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics%29 (or some other technique from your textbook/class notes, if applicable) and post your thoughts and attempts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to count the integer solutions of
$$x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4+x_5=32$$
where
$$x_i\gt3,\text{ i.e., }x_i\ge4.$$
If you substitute
$$x_i=4+y_i$$
this becomes
$$(4+y_1)+(4+y_2)+(4+y_3)+(4+y_4)+(4+y_5)=32\text{ with }4+y_i\ge4,$$
i.e.,
$$y_1+y_2+y_3+y_4+y_5=12\text{ with }y_i\ge0;$$
the number of solutions is of course$$\binom{16}4=1820.$$
If you prefer, you can substitute
$$x_i=3+z_i$$
and the problem becomes
$$(3+z_1)+(3+z_2)+(3+z_3)+(3+z_4)+(3+z_5)=32,\ 3+z_i\gt3,$$
i.e.,
$$z_1+z_2+z_3+z_4+z_5=17,\ z_i\gt0.$$

Answer (score 1):

Use the stars and bars formula but since each x variable needs at least 3 u must choose
                            $c((n-3k) + k-1, k-1)$

where k is the number of variables(number of x variables) and n is the number that it totals (32). Hope it helps.

Comment: Please formatt your post using MathJax

Comment: Sorry Im new to this forum and have no idea what mathjax is

Comment: Well for one thing you should put all math expressions within $ signs. Have a look at this - http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference